# Question about Yoroi and Ledger (restore security)

Tags: wallet, yoroi, ledger, seed-phrase

I'm writing today because I have read some issues about Yoroi in the reddit of Cardano. It seems that many people have problems when they want to restore their account. Some of them have lost their ada so I prefer to discuss the matter here !
(here is the link of the reddit's discussion : https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/comments/tzx29t/hardware_wallet_derivation_path_problem_already )

Currently, I have a Yoroi account which was, when I created it a simple yoroi account (thus, it gave me a seed phrase). But after I have bought a ledger S and so I decided to link this ledger to my yoroi account.

Now, when I connect to my yoroi account I see that I have a "Yoroi-Ledger" (I've put a picture so that you can see).

But the question I'm asking is :
When you add a nano S to an existing yoroi wallet, is the security the same than if you start a brand new yoroi wallet to integrate with the ledger nano S at the beginning?
And if yes what is the procedure to restore it?

[image]

There is no clear answer on this subject to I thank you in advance for your help !

Have a great day !

Answer (score 1):

Ledger uses a different derivation path than the default [Icarus derivation](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip3/) used by hot wallets like Yoroi and Daedalus. This means that entering the seed phrase you generated on a hardware wallet directly into a hot wallet (like Yoroi) will result in a different wallet being generated/restored than the one on the ledger.

In practice, this means it is probably a good idea to have an extra "backup" ledger device in case the primary one fails and you need quick access to your assets. However, if (worst case scenario) Ledger the company drops off the face of the earth, it isn't too much of a problem. At the end of the day, many many people use Ledger, so someone will automate Ledger's derivation path and make wallet recovery without the device easier.

Comment: all right, thank you for your answer and your time, I appreciate ! 

So in your opinion there is no major risk at this time? 

The question I have is also if my computer is broken, I have a new one, I have to download Yoroi again, how can I set up my old account on the new yoroi extansion? Because I see a good number of people who don't succeed in having back their old account because there is no seed phrase.

I start to understand that the ADA are in my ledger so not at risk but without Yoroi account I have no interface to see or use them. 

Thank you again, it is great to discuss !

Comment: Put it this way: your seed is your ADA, and your seed is on the ledger. So, your ledger is your ADA. If your computer breaks, you can restore your wallet using your ledger device. To restore the wallet in Yoroi, simply select the "Connect to Hardware Wallet" option. Always do a dry run (testnet or small funds on mainnet) if you are unsure about anything.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer ! 
It can seem strange for you but in fact I'm scared that my Ada are currently in my Yoroi Account and not on my ledger. 

Indeed, I have seen lots of people talking about bug on Yoroi (it seems that this app is not liked by the community..) and they did not succeed in find their account again after deleting the app. 

It is hard to visualize where are your coins sometimes and when you see some bug with the app you start panicking !

Comment: On Yoroi, it says "wallet ledger" so I believe that they are on my ledger.. It would have been great to be able to see on ledger live the exact amount on my key but I can't !